# PCL Segmentation in ROS: Missing headers

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to split a pointcloud into segments by using PCL in fuerte but, for example, the file "min_cut_segmentation.h" is missing. I tried it with ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable getting the same problem.

Is there a way to use those segmentations from PCL within ROS ?

############### Edit 01: ###############

There is no error message in this case. The include files for (most) PCL-segmentation are just not there within ROS, but they are in the standalone version of PCL. As far as I can tell there seems to be no way to use those files out of the standalone version within ROS.

############## Edit 02:

http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/

Now it works

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44651/pcl-segmentation-in-ros:-missing-headers/) by [DontPanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3144/dontpanic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-27**:
Please always copy-paste the complete error message and make sure you read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, min_cut_segmentation.h is not in perception_pcl in ROS. You can find it in PCL 1.7 source code.

---

Originally posted by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) with karma: 231 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-28**:
http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/